# How do I create a list of different each single result repeated N times?

Tags: python, loops

I've recently started learning Python. So my question might be too basic.

```
from eth_account import Account
import secrets
priv = secrets.token_hex(32)
private_key = "0x" + priv
acct = Account.from_key(private_key)
print(private_key, acct.address)
```

So this is the code to create a random eth address and private key.
And from here, I wanted to create 10 each different results.
Now I'm stuck here.
I tried using 'For.. in" loop and then it only showed the same addresses and private keys repeated.

Could you give me a hand please?

Comment: Make sure you do not replace the same variable with a new value every time in the loop. You should google for *lists* and maybe even *list comprehensions*. You will need those to hold the 10 addresses. One simple variable won't be able to hold 10 addresses.

Comment: you should show the code you actually tried, with the for loop, so we can say where it went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to isolate your code into a function like this:

from eth_account import Account
import secrets

```
from eth_account import Account
import secrets

def gen(private_key_prefix:str = "0x"):
    priv = secrets.token_hex(32)
    private_key = private_key_prefix + priv
    return private_key, Account.from_key(private_key).address
    
    
print([gen() for _ in range(10)])
```

This return 10 differens combinations of secret address address